# Add column to output function

Tags: r, multiple-columns, spotify

I'm struggling with the following, hopefully you can help me out on this one.

I'm using a function to get all the chart data from Spotify for a date range. However, the output of the function doesn't tell you what day is linked to the 200 tracks that get returned. I tried adding columns but because the length of the function output and the initial days input are different this doesn't seem to work.

```
datums <- seq(as.Date('2018-04-01'),as.Date('2018-05-05'),by = 1)
dates <- list(datums)

country <- rep(c('nl'), each = 30)


chart <- purrr::map2_df(country, dates, ~ spotifycharts::chart_top200_daily(.x, .y))
```

The output gives you:

```
position track.name    artist          streams url                                                  
      <int> <chr>         <chr>             <int> <chr>                                                
 1        1 Sofiane       Boef             299735 https://open.spotify.com/track/7aK0LpCyxzN5K9pAP20MVC
 2        2 Beetje Moe    Kevin            220181 https://open.spotify.com/track/5ncYmvTAX7RbJSvoFGrSkv
 3        3 Lil Craney    Kraantje Pappie  185912 https://open.spotify.com/track/6mhojtIauujcoXxlGsihh1
 4        4 Drip          SFB              171255 https://open.spotify.com/track/7ulH79Yk90PkLsEjYjVyif
 5        5 God's Plan    Drake            158205 https://open.spotify.com/track/2XW4DbS6NddZxRPm5rMCeY
```

(each day returns 200 tracks)

I want the chart date to be added as well as the country code.

I'm rather new to R so apologies for the newbie question - also tried looking up the solution but nothing seems to work.

Much appreciated!

Comment: You should show us a few rows of your actual data so we know what it looks like.

Comment: Just edited the post to give you an idea. Hope this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify a few things. Your dates don't need to be a list—a vector of dates will suffice for `map_df`. You also don't need a list or vector of country names if the country is staying the same. Inside the function that `map` uses, you get a data frame from `chart_top200_daily`, on which you can call `mutate` to add your date column.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(spotifycharts)

datums <- seq(as.Date('2018-04-01'), as.Date('2018-05-05'), by = 1)
# dates <- list(datums)

chart <- map_df(datums, function(date) {
    chart_top200_daily("nl", date) %>%
        mutate(date = date)
})

chart
#> # A tibble: 7,000 x 6
#>    position track.name    artist          streams url           date      
#>       <int> <chr>         <chr>             <int> <chr>         <date>    
#>  1        1 Sofiane       Boef             299735 https://open… 2018-04-01
#>  2        2 Beetje Moe    Kevin            220181 https://open… 2018-04-01
#>  3        3 Lil Craney    Kraantje Pappie  185912 https://open… 2018-04-01
#>  4        4 Drip          SFB              171255 https://open… 2018-04-01
#>  5        5 God's Plan    Drake            158205 https://open… 2018-04-01
#>  6        6 Ze Willen Mee Hardwell         154086 https://open… 2018-04-01
#>  7        7 Catch Up      Josylvio         142023 https://open… 2018-04-01
#>  8        8 FRIENDS       Marshmello       140276 https://open… 2018-04-01
#>  9        9 Non Stop      Ronnie Flex      139419 https://open… 2018-04-01
#> 10       10 Fan           Ronnie Flex      132936 https://open… 2018-04-01
#> # ... with 6,990 more rows
```

Created on 2018-05-06 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).